# Trying to fire an intent from a ContentObserver

Tags: android, android-context

I'd like to fire an intent from the `onChange()` method of my `ContentObserver`. I'm trying to get a Service to run when an SMS is sent, hence the `ContentObserver`, but Eclipse is giving me errors because it cannot resolve "context". Below is my code for the class.

```
public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {

public SmsObserver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);

    // On outgoing SMS, do this
    Intent update = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, update, 0);

    try {
        pendingIntent.send();
    } catch (CanceledException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is there some reason you cant just pass the application context into the SmsObserver when the instance is created?

```
public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {

    private Context context;
    public SmsObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Invoking class:

```
new SmsObserver(handler, getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: Just be careful and pass the application context and _not_ an activity context!